# jeditable showing placeholder text in edit textbox

Tags: jeditable

I have an issue with jeditable and trying to customize the style of the placeholder text.

```
        $(".labeledit").editable("....", {
            event: "click",
            onblur: "submit",
            width:($(".labeledit").width() + 40) + "px",
            placeholder: "<span class='placeholder'>add label</span>",
            tooltip: "Click to update"
        });
```

In the placeholder text I add a span and associate a class. This works fine in the view but when I click on the add label text it places the placeholder text into the textbox so I get

```
<span class='placeholder'>add label</span>
```

appearing in the textbox.

If I just have placeholder: "add label" then the add label text doesn't show in the textbox.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where's the HTML code for element with `labeledit` class?

Comment: Django template: `<div class="labeledit editable" id="text-compoundlabel-{{ compound.pk }}" style="display: inline; font-size: 11px; font-style: italic;">{{ compound.label }}</div>`

Comment: Afraid not. Need to spend some more time on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is! Instead of:

```
...
placeholder: "<span class='placeholder'>add label</span>",
...
```

try switching the quote marks:

```
...
placeholder: '<span class="placeholder">add label</span>',
...
```